# Why index out of range error in reader object

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

[image]

The result set of executeReader is list of items

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    mailbody +=
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + reader["DevName"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["DevId"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["LocationID"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["LocationName"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["SubLocationID"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["IPV6"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["LastConnected"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["LastDisconnected"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["Online"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["HardwareSerialNumber"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["ServiceProviderID"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["DateLastModified"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
}
```

[image]

this is the result set from stored proc

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which programming language is that? Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: At least one of the column names you are using in the code is wrong.

Comment: can you please specify stored procedure

Comment: added the result set image

Comment: @ZoharPeled is right that's the problem. And your error message is even telling you which column is the problem it can't find the column 'LocationName'

Answer (score 0):

Your SP is missing a few columns that you are referencing:

```
"<td>" + reader["LocationName"].ToString() + "</td>" +
"<td>" + reader["LastConnected"].ToString() + "</td>" +
"<td>" + reader["LastDisconnected"].ToString() + "</td>" +
```

The last 2 are probably meant to be `LastConnTime` and `LastDisconnTime`. Make sure the names match 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Either specify column with name 'LocationName' in your Stored Procedure or remove the line

```
   "<td>" + reader["LocationName"].ToString() + "</td>" +
```

This is the part of error message that is telling you which column it couldn't find:

[image]

EDIT: There may be few more columns that don't match the Stored Procedure output, but all you need to do is take a look @ additional information part of your error.

EDIT2: Looking @ your result set from Stored Procedure it will also have problems finding columns: 'LastConnected' and 'LastDisconnected' so the solution will be the same either remove those rows  or rename it (like in the example bellow) to the column names provided by your Stored Procedure

```
    "<td>" + reader["LastConnTime"].ToString() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + reader["LastDisconnTime"].ToString() + "</td>" +
```